# How to add a character before a specific symbol in a variable?

Tags: perl

I have a user defined variables that is a `user@domain.com`

Using perl I need to add "sc" at the end of user and before the @ symbol.

so if:

```
$user = "user@domain.com"
$string = "sc"
```

I need to come out with the result of

```
$user-id = "usersc@domain.com"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$user =~ s/(?=@)/sc/;
```

or

```
$user =~ s/@/sc@/;
```

or

```
$user =~ s/^[^@]*\K/sc/;    # Assumes "@" will always be present.
```

---

Of course, none of those will work if `$user` doesn't contain the correct string to begin with.

```
$user = "user@domain.com";
```

is the same as

```
$user = "user" . join($", @domain) . ".com";
```

Given that `@domain` doesn't exist, that's the same as

```
$user = "user.com";
```

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! You want

```
my $user = "user\@domain.com";
```

or

```
my $user = 'user@domain.com';
```

to create var `$user` with the string `user@domain.com`.

Comment: ...or `$user = reverse( reverse($user) =~ s/@\K/cs/r );` :)

Comment: Does not seem to work using:                                      $user = "user@live.com";
$user =~ s/^[^@]*\K/sc/;
print $user;                                                                       Returns  user.comsc  the other two return user.com

Comment: Are you sure your string contains `user@domain.com`? The code you showed does not produce such a string. Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: `$user = "user@live.com";` should be `my $user = 'user@live.com';`. Updated answer.

Comment: I don't want to take sides here, but I love the fact that I can switch almost seamlessly between English and Perl while reading your posts. I wouldn't change it one bit.